# Can we store a database in firebase, make changes and retrieve?

Tags: excel, firebase

I have a data set in excel and I want to store it in a Firebase. I have to make changes in it like adding some columns using website and retrieve the values for the changes.
How to proceed?

Comment: what platform? android | iOS | javascript?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem, You want sync your excel changes to firebase.If so,then take your data on spread sheet from excel file

you can go with [Google Spread Sheets](https://www.google.com/sheets/about/) and [Zapier](https://zapier.com/)

What you need,

1.Zapier Account

2.Google Acount

On Zapier account,make a Zap which will get data from your Spread Sheet and instert it at specified locaion on firebase

[Example](https://zapier.com/zapbook/zaps/3281/add-new-google-sheets-spreadsheet-rows-to-firebase-as-new-records/)

Once you have setup then it will automatically insert your sheet data to firebase. But note one thing,setup your Zap first before taking your data to spread sheet from excel beacuase Zapier will not check for existing rows.It always start checking rows after you have setup Zap